# Android: Make button disappear immediately after successful purchase using Iab Billing Processor

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-developer-api

How can i make the buy button disappear immediately after a successful purchase using Iab Billing Processor in my app?

I'm using a Bottom Navigation activity with Fragments for the pages. I have three fragment pages. The third fragment page I have a button on there that is an in-app buy option. Everything works fine, my only problem is, when the purchase is successful the buy button will not disappear and Toast will not popup confirming the purchase is successful even though I have it added to the onProductPurchased Method. I have to click the buy button a second time to pull the method below. I don't want that. I want the below method to pull immediately after the purchase is successful.

**Here's what I have for the onProductPurchased method and the other methods:**

```
@Override
public void onProductPurchased(@NonNull String productId, @Nullable 
TransactionDetails details) {
    removeAds.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Purchase Complete! Thank You!", 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } 

@Override
public void onPurchaseHistoryRestored() {
removeAds.setVisibility(View.GONE);
Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Your Purchase has been restored!", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


@Override
public void onBillingError(int errorCode, @Nullable Throwable error) {
removeAds.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Purchase Failed!", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onBillingInitialized() {
bp.loadOwnedPurchasesFromGoogle();
}
```

The onActivityResult seems to not be pulling the requestCode, resultCode, and it's not pulling the Intent data. I've tried it two ways and to no avail.

**Way 1 (Failed):**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
if (!bp.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
}
```

}

**Way 2 (Failed):**

```
@Override
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {
    Fragment f = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(this.getId());
    f.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Both of them are not working.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
if (bp != null) {
    bp.release();
}
super.onDestroy();
}
```

**The beginning of my Java Class:**

```
public class MenuOptions extends Fragment implements 
BillingProcessor.IBillingHandler {
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

BillingProcessor bp;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public MenuOptions() {

}

public static MenuOptions newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
MenuOptions fragment = new MenuOptions();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
fragment.setArguments(args);
return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
if (getArguments() != null) {
    mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
    mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
 }
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu_options, container, 
false);

bp = new 

BillingProcessor(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity())
.getApplicationContext(), null, MenuOptions.this);

removeAds.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        bp.purchase(getActivity(), "android.test.purchased");
    }
});

return v;

}
```

I think that the buy button isn't disappearing immediately after successful purchase because of the requestCode and resultCode not being retrieved properly. I've tested it and it doesn't seem to be pulling nothing. Nothing I'm doing is fixing that problem. I've researched online for my problem and I have found the same question asked but unfortunately the answers didn't resolve my problem. I've never done buy options with fragments before. Is there anything I am forgetting? I appreciate the help in advanced!

Comment: is the parent activity receiving the `onActivityResult`? make sure you're not intercepting `onActivityResult ` it in the parent activity or it won't propagate down to the fragment

Comment: Thanks for your comment Jon. I did as you said. I cut the onActivityResult from the fragment to the MainActivity and I received an error in the logcat when I made a test purchase. Here's that error message...

Comment: 08-25 21:48:51.838 30803-30803/com.testapp.billingprocessor E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.testapp.billingprocessor , PID: 30803
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=32459, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.testapp.billingprocessor /com.testapp.billingprocessor .MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.anjlab.android.iab.v3.BillingProcessor.handleActivityResult(int, int, android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference

Comment: I meant that I copied the onActivityResult from the fragment class and I pasted it to the MainActivity Class and the error above happened when I made a test purchase.